# Why Batch Process not working by Task Scheduler User Administrator?

Tags: batch-file, task, windows-task-scheduler, administrator

I have a process for ETL, in a .bat file which:

- copy .xlsx file to a directory
- open the Excel file by progress
- copy the information to progress database

***When I run the .bat file by the user: TableauAdmin in the explorer:***

- it works fine!
- TableauAdmin appears as the owner of the .log files

Then I created a scheduled task with the owner: TableauAdmin, and user to run the task: TableauAdmin, in Windows Server 2012. With the Highest privileges, whether or not the user is logged in...

If I try to run the task I got this error:

> Error occurred while accessing component property/method: open.
> Microsoft Excel cannot access the file
> 'd:\ses\dat\FacturaMes-240817.xlsx'. There are several possible
> reasons: Error code: 0x80020009 d:\ses\pro\sescargaexcelbd.p (5890)

And now, the owner of the .log files, is the user "Administrators".

Also, I am writing in the log files the %USERNAME% and appears "TableauAdmin"!

Is not working the progress-office-excel option by changing the account TableauAdmin to Administrators where is included TableauAdmin.

**What to change so every thing works fine?**

Today I changed the User that runs the Task to Administrators...

Now everything is working fine, but the user it is running it does not appears Administrators,

The User that appears running the process is another Administrator....

- So the Excel File is owned by Administrators
- And opened by Administrators
- But is running by other Administrator, not TableauAdmin....

**Why is it running OK now?**

Comment: `And now, the owner of the .log files, is the user "Administrators".` Well - there's your clue. The batch is being run under the `administrators` user so the environment setting will be that of *that* user, not of *Tableauadmin*. Change the user in the the task scheduler or set the environment variables in the batch to those which suite *Tableauadmin* (but in that case, the logs will still be owned by *Administrators*)

Comment: Scheduling a task to run whether the user is logged on or not means the scheduler service executes it in session 0 (Services). This session is isolated from creating a user interface, and a lot of GUI apps will fail, and this likely includes MS Excel.

Comment: You're mistaken in assuming that this has anything to do with the log files being owned by the Administrators group. Your process is running as "TableauAdmin", which is a member of the Administrators group. Normally UAC logs this user own with this group disabled (actually enabled only for deny ACEs). It's enabled in the access token of the *elevated* logon. Whenever the Administrators group is enabled, by policy the system sets the owner of files created as the Administrators group itself rather than the admin user. This allows all admins to consistently access files created by any admin.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this link -> https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dataaccesstechnologies/2012/12/19/error-microsoft-office-excel-cannot-access-the-file-while-accessing-microsoft-office-11-0-object-library-from-ssis/

For Windows 2008 Server x64: Create the following directory:

```
    C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop
```

For Windows 2008 Server x86: Create the following directory:

```
    C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Desktop
```